# How can the Java InputStream function `available()` be implemented using the C language?

Tags: java, c, networking, inputstream, ioctl

How can the Java InputStream function `available()` be implemented using the C language?

This function returns an estimate of the number of bytes which can be read from an InputStream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for that InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the `ioctl(2)` function, `FIONREAD` option.